# Is there any way to find sum of sequence generated by formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have such sequence:

$2^2$, $7^2$, $12^2$, $17^2$, $22^2$, ...

I found a formula to generate **n-th** term:

$(5\cdot n+2)^2$

And I need to find a sum of those numbers:

4, 49, 144, 289, 484, ...

Can you help me with steps I should do?

---

This one would suite better for ordering:
$(5\cdot n-3)^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could develop $(5n+2)²$ and then use the formulae to compute $\sum_{k=1}^nk$ and $\sum_{k=1}^nk^2$.

Comment: Can you give me more details?

Comment: $\sum_{k-1}^n(5k-3)²=\sum_{k=1}^n(25k^2-30k+9)=25\sum_{k=1}^nk^2-30\sum_{k=1}^nk+9\sum_{k=1}^n1$

Comment: So, there is no formula, where I can put $n$ and get such sum without those loops to calculate $n^2$

Comment: Yes, because $\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\{4,49,144,289,484,...\}=a_n=25n^2-30n+9=(5n-3)^2$

the sum for **m-th** term:

$\sum_1 ^m(5n-3)^2=\frac{1}{6}\cdot (m+1)(5m^2-65m+54)$

the sum for **m-th** term:

$\sum_1 ^m(5n+2)^2=\frac{1}{6}\cdot (m+1)(50m^2+85m+24)$

Comment: This formula gives n-th term and I need a sum of first n terms.

Comment: @viakondratiuk mark v on one of the two answers